# Scrolling not triggered on select element with parent scrolling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So despite my attempts to find something online to answer this issue, I have had no luck.
I have been trying to create a "mostly" css approach to adding horizontal scrolling to a select list.

However, if I have a select inside of a scrollable container where the container height is shorter than the select's height (to trigger a vertical scroll on the outer container), then the ***scrolling*** behavior is either *wonky* (in the case of a normal select) or *none at all* (in the case of adding a `multiple="multiple"` attribute to the select) in IE or Chrome. But, it does seem to function properly in FireFox

**Question:** Is there any css/html strucuture work around? Any alternative jQuery/js workaround?

http://jsfiddle.net/Qn6TH/3/

```
div.ScrollableSelect { overflow: auto; }
#availableCodes { width: 600px; height: 1715px; }

<div class="ScrollableSelect" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
    <select id="availableCodes" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the problem and what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Problem: Scrolling doesn't work, Question: What can be done to fix it? ;)

Comment: The scrolling seems to be working fine for me (chrome) what exactly isn't working?

Comment: If you want the options in the select to scroll vertically, you need to set the height on the select itself.  Horizontally is going to give you a lot of oddness--it's a replaced element.  Most browsers should scroll horizontally if a width is set on select, but it's going to vary according to browser/OS  (@multiple enables shift click, and shifts default UI to a multiple select mode; keep that in mind if that's not what you want)